# Integral of a radial function on the closed unit ball

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a Riemann integrable function, $|x|$ be the Euclidean norm: $|(x_1,\dots,x_k)| = \sqrt{\sum x_i^2}$, and $B$ be the closed unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$: $B = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: |x| \le 1\}$. I know that the function $g: B \to \mathbb R$ defined by $g(x) = f(|x|)$ is Riemann integrable on $B$. I want a hint to to show that
$$\int _B g = S\int_0^1f(x)x^{n-1}dx$$
where $S$ is the $k-1$ dimensional volume of the unit sphere.
I know how to show it if $f$ is continuous. I was told to use the result for continuous $f$ (which I know for all sub intervals of $[0,1]$) and appropriate Darboux sums. I tried doing that, but I couldn't get anything useful from $f$'s Darboux sums.

Thanks.

Comment: Here it is convenient to use approximation arguments involving Lebesgue's integral. After all, this formula is true for any $g \in L^1(B)$. One approach is to use the fact that $C(B)$ is dense in $L^1(B)$.

Comment: @Mason is there a way without the Lebesgue integral?

Comment: Can you adapt your proof for continuous functions? Alternatively, there are results for approximating the integral of a Riemann integrable function by integrals of continuous functions. See proposition 3.1.11 on page 111 of https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf

Comment: @Mason Thanks, I solved it